# SQL library trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle-sqldeveloper

Im trying to make a library database. I would like to ensure that one book can be borrowed just to one person at a time. I have no expirience with triggers so I thought I might ask you.

```
      create table "book"  (
       "book_id"          INTEGER                         not null,
       "condition"               VARCHAR2(50),
       "isbn"               VARCHAR2(50)                    not null,
       constraint PK_BOOK primary key ("book_id")
    );

    create table "borrowed"  (
   "book_id"          INTEGER                         not null,
   "borrowed_id"        INTEGER                         not null,
   "user_id"            INTEGER                         not null,
   "date_borrowing"     DATE                            not null,
   "date_returning"    DATE                            not null,
   "returned"          SMALLINT                        not null,
   constraint PK_BORROWED primary key ("book_id", "borrowed_id")
);
```

atribute "returned" has just yes or no value (1 or 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a trigger for this.  Your borrowed table should be structured like this.  Note the use of a virtual column, which requires Oracle 11g+:

```
create table borrowed  (
   borrowed_id INTEGER not null primary key, -- this should be set to a unique id for each row, using your preferred method
   book_id INTEGER not null,
   user_id INTEGER not null,
   date_borrowing DATE not null,
   date_returning DATE  not null,
   date_actualreturn DATE,
   returned as (case date_actualreturn is null then 0 else 1 end)
);
```

Then, you want `date_actualreturn` to have at most one `NULL` value per book.  You can do this with a unique index or constraint:

```
create table borrowed  (
   borrowed_id INTEGER not null primary key, -- this should be set to a unique id for each row, using your preferred method
   book_id INTEGER not null,
   user_id INTEGER not null,
   date_borrowing DATE not null,
   date_returning DATE  not null,
   date_actualreturn DATE,
   returned as (case date_actualreturn is null then 0 else 1 end),
   constraint unq_only_one_book_borrowed unique
      (coalesce(date_actualreturn, date '1900-01-01'), book_id)
);
```

This creates a unique constraint on the column.  If a book has not been returned, the date always looks the same -- so the same book cannot be borrowed twice.  And, voila!  No trigger.

Comment: We are using Oracle 10g

Comment: @klimatomas . . . You can still create the unique index using a function-based index.  The virtual column is convenient for defining `returned`, but not needed for the constraint.